# How to get the asynchronous data in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to set a service and want the controllers in my app get the data from the service.

I have something like

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Product',
    function(Product) {
        var products

        //Product is a $resource object to send an http request
        Product$.query({
            id: 123
        }, function(object) {
            setProducts(object); 
        });

        var setProducts = function(object) {
            products = object;
        }

        var getProducts = function() {
            return products;
        }

        return {
            setProducts: setProducts,            
            getProducts: getProducts
        };
    }
]);
```

in my another controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('productController', ['$scope', 'testService',
    function($scope, testService) {
        //return undefined...
        console.log(testService.getProducts())
    }
]);

//testService.getProducts() returns undefined.
```

I think the reason is because I am making `$http` request and it's asynchronous so the testService has no idea what the product is when the app first loads. How do I fix this issue? Thanks so much!

Comment: Take a look at the Promise/Deferred pattern. AngularJS has its own implementation ($q).

Comment: You have mistyped the query: you typed `Product$.query` instead of `Product.$query`. Another thing, the `$query` function returns an object that will be automagically filled up when request is fulfilled so you can assign it directly to your variable `products`

Comment: Sorry, it's `query` not `$query` [link] (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a promise "q$" to deal with asynch calls:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('testService', ['Product',
    function(Product, $q) {
        var products



        var setProducts = function(object) {
            products = object;
        }

        var getProducts = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //Product is a $resource object to send an http request
            Product$.query({
                id: 123
            }, function(object) {
                setProducts(object); 
                deferred.resolve(object);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            setProducts: setProducts,            
            getProducts: getProducts
        };
    }
]);


angular.module('myApp').controller('productController', ['$scope', 'testService',
    function($scope, testService) {
        //use a promise
        testService.getProducts().then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        function (error) { 
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
]);
```

The promise has two call backs one for complete and one for error.  You can deal with the errors in your view model as needed.

Comment: exactly what i need. tyvm